# How to improve naming for Tasklist and Task

Tags: terminology, information-architecture

I have a section in an application, that lists all the Task Lists (or ToDo Lists, or Check Lists) assigned. Each list has several Tasks (or ToDos, or Checks) inside.

What do you think would be the most appropriate naming structure?

I have split the list into 2 sections, **Tasklists for me** and **Tasklists for others**. Inside each list there's one or many Tasks.

The main problem i have is that the container word (Task List, ToDo List or Check List) is too long and probably not commonly used among the users.

The reality is that they use the 2nd level word (Task, ToDo, Check, or even List) as a generic label for Task Lists or for individual tasks. So they don't really have a pattern i can explode.

I need to take a position based on this, so there's no correct solution, but a least incorrect one. The only requirement is to make an explicit difference between the **Container list** and the **Content**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if you simply call them "Lists" to cover all the bases, and have a "My List" and "Others List" section? Then the content items within could be check boxes, to dos, tasks, events, whatever you like, either of a single type or mixed and matched. Anything within a List could simply be a List Item - taking a cue from old-school HTML!